# Spot the pattern. There is none

Tags: pattern, sequence

Look at these pictures:
[image: The pattern]
What's the next picture?

As requested, bellow is a set of possible answers. You don't have to look at them to find the correct answer.

> [image: List of answers]

Comment: So, if I think I know the answer with a high level of confidence, I'll have to draw it out, save it as a picture, and upload the picture as part of my answer. Seems a bit of work to me. Puzzles of this sort usually provide a set of "possible" answers to choose from, so that people _don't_ have to fiddle with images.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin, thanks for the suggestion. Done!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The next picture is

> [image]
>  (number 7 in the options list)

Reason:

> There is exactly one diagonal line in each picture, which seems to rotate between four positions/orientations. Following this pattern, the next picture should have a forward diagonal line in the bottom half.
>
>  The vertical/horizontal lines seems to follow those on a 7-segment display: although the aspect ratio is altered, the vertical lines seem to be split into two components, while the horizontal lines are always intact. The lines themselves don't show anything notable, but the segments that *aren't* visible (the negative space, in a way, presumably hinted at by the "there is none" in the title) form numbers. In fact, they are the digits of pi (3.14159...). The next digit of pi is 2, so taking the segments that don't appear in the 7-segment display of 2 and combining with the diagonal line yields the final answer.

Comment: Yes! By "there is none" I actually meant that no pattern has been found in the digits of pi (but that's not really important).